# Adding Controls to a StackPanel from a BackroundWorker thread

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I have created a demo, that will hopefully demonstrate the problem I have been having for the last couple of days.

I have created a simple class named ***Data Supplier***  with a single public static method named ***GenerateRandomInt()*** this is to simulate having a process which might take some time. The code for the aforementioned class can be found below:

```
class DataSupplier
    {
        public static int GenerateRandomInt()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return rnd.Next();
        }
    }
```

My MainWindow simple contains a ScrollViewer with StackPanel embedded inside it named ***stackPanel1*** , also a Button named ***button1*** the XAML for this is shown below:

```
<Window x:Class="ThreadingDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Name="button1"
                Content="Generate 10 Labels"
                Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What I want to achieve, is when I click ***button1*** 10 labels are generated, which display a random number using the static ***DataSupplier.GetRandomInt()*** method. However I want them to be displayed one by one, i.e. as soon as they are individually created. The codebehind for my ***MainWindow*** is shown below:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private BackgroundWorker worker;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }

        void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    //create a new label, and set it's content to a randomly generated number
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Content = DataSupplier.GenerateRandomInt();

                    //add this label to stackPanel1
                    stackPanel1.Children.Add(lbl);
                }
            }));
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.IsEnabled = false;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

However, what is happening is that nothing visually appears until all 10 of my *randomly generated labels* have been added to stackPanel1.

Is there anyway I can program this so that each label appears as each one is created? Whilst also ensuring that my UI remains responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is you've created a Background Worker to offload work from the UI thread, but the operation that takes a long time `GenerateRandomInt()` is getting dispatched right back to the UI thread and thus causes your app to start freezing.

With something like:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    int x = DataSupplier.GenerateRandomInt();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      DispatcherPriority.Normal,
      (Action)(() => {
        Label lbl = new Label { Content = x };
        stackPanel1.Children.Add(lbl);
      }));
  }
}
```

The "long running function" is run in the background thread and just the UI stuff is dispatched to the UI thread thereby giving you what you expect. Originally we created a thread and ended up sending the work we wanted it to do, back to the caller making it pointless.

Now if you can use **.net 4.5**, this can be made a whole lot simpler such as:

the long running static func:

```
internal class DataSupplier {
  public static async Task<int> GenerateRandomInt() {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return rnd.Next();
  }
}
```

and in your MainWindow's code-behind:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  button1.IsEnabled = false;
  await AddLabels();
  button1.IsEnabled = true;
}

private async Task AddLabels() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    Label lb = new Label { Content = await DataSupplier.GenerateRandomInt() };
    stackPanel1.Children.Add(lb);
  }
}
```

This will give you the same result and be simpler(just my opinion)

Comment: This right here was my exact problem, I was locking up UI when I directly set the content property with the timely static method. Now that I have done it as you suggested my problem has been fixed.

Also this program I wrote was simply a demo to demonstrate the issue I was having with my actual code, and I have since fixed it because of your comment. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try using BeginInvoke instead.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    string content = DataSupplier.GenerateRandomInt();
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
   {
     lbl.Content = content;
//create a new label, and set it's content to a randomly generated number
     Label lbl = new Label();  
    //add this label to stackPanel1
     stackPanel1.Children.Add(lbl);
                        }));
    Thread.Sleep(100);
  }
```

Invoke will execute synchronously, so when the call has been executed, your thread will return, BeginInvoke will instead execute asynchronously.
I have added a thread.sleep to suspend background thread for a while.
In this case all the work done by background thread is to update the UI, so UI is always busy.

Comment: This seems to be yielding the same result as I was having before. Also the UI remains unresponsive whilst the random numbers are being added to the StackPanel

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't mean to set the 'lbl.Content' property before the instantiating the 'Label'. When I change the code slightly to set the content after 'lbl' has been created. The code is able to execute however I still have the same issue. However it seems to take longer (I imagine due to the recent addition of 'Thread.Sleep(1000)')

Answer (score 0):

try with setting `DispatcherPriority` to `Render` in your worker`_DoWork`. It should fix the rendering

```
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    //create a new label, and set it's content to a randomly generated number
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Content = DataSupplier.GenerateRandomInt();

                    //add this label to stackPanel1
                    stackPanel1.Children.Add(lbl);
                }
            }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

Comment: I don't suppose you could expand upon this. What is the exact line of code I would need to achieve this?

Comment: I have brought the 'Dispatcher.Invoke' inside the for loop, and with your 'DispatcherPriority.Render' The labels do indeed appear one at a time inside 'stackPanel1'. Which is great!

However, the UI does still remain unresponsive until all the labels have been added to the StackPanel

Answer (score 0):

Report your progress, so your code will look like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private BackgroundWorker worker;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Content = e.ProgressPercentage;
            stackPanel1.Children.Add(lbl);
        }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(DataSupplier.GenerateRandomInt());
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.IsEnabled = false;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private int GenerateRandomInt(int i)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return i;
    }
}

class DataSupplier
{
    public static int GenerateRandomInt()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return rnd.Next();
    }
}
```